# CakePHP 3 View to Variable

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

my question is give it a way to parse a view file (.ctp) into a variable ? 
I want to create a ajax function that gives a ctp file or better says the content of this back. 
The call from the javascript to cakephp's controller work but now i doesnt now how i can get my specified ctp file in the template folder parse it into a variable and send it back to the javascript function.

Comment: You only want the ctp-output parsed by ajax? Set in the controller `if ($this->request->is('ajax'))` and output it to a ctp of your choice. And then just parse it with ajax.

Comment: can you give me a code example pls

Comment: in this moment i return a string with this "echo ' message '" but i want to return the completet content of a ctp file

Comment: i tried that https://gist.github.com/rakeshtembhurne/6038128 but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say, you are using the controller `sites` and the view is `index`.

```
app/Controller/SitesController.php:

public function index() {
    if($this->request->is('ajax') {
        // prepare output for ajax. best way to do is to prevent styled output
        $this->render('TestView/index');
    }
}
```

In your `TestView/index.ctp` you can now prepare your output for ajax and just call the controller/action URL by AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/sites/index",
    success: function(reponse) {
        console.log(response); // here comes the output from /sites/index
    }
});
```